# How do I overwrite an Value in a JSONObject which contains a JSONArray?

Tags: java, json

So I have an JSON data which looks like this. But I need to invert in one specific scene and one specific element ("iCalstate") its state.

For example if its true, it should overwrite it false. After it has overwritten the specific element it should write this json type to an file called test.json.

```
{"scene": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "element": [
            {"iCalstate": "false"},
            {"iCalstate": "false"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "element": [
            {"iCalstate": "false"},
            {"iCalstate": "false"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "element": [
            {"iCalstate": "false"},
            {"iCalstate": "false"}
        ]
    }
]}
```

What I tried so far:
I have made methods to get the JSONObject & JSONArrays, I tried to create an if which does invert the value (it works). The thing that I didn't manage is to invert it on a specific sceneindex and elemindex --> any help would be gladly appreciated

```
        int sceneindex = 0;
        int elemindex = 0;

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray scene = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray element = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray relement = datain.getIcalSettingsElement(sceneindex); //gets the element from the "olf"

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                json.put("scene", scene);

                JSONObject node = new JSONObject();
                scene.put(node);
                node.put("id", i);
                node.put("element", element);
            }
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
                if (ii == elemindex) {
                    JSONObject enode = new JSONObject();
                    String invwrite = "";
                    if (relement.getJSONObject(ii).getString("iCalstate").equals("true")) {
                        invwrite = "false";
                    } else if (relement.getJSONObject(ii).getString("iCalstate").equals("false")) {
                        invwrite = "true";
                    }
                    enode.put("iCalstate", invwrite);
                    element.put(enode);
                } else {
                    JSONObject enode = new JSONObject();
                    String write = relement.getJSONObject(ii).getString("iCalstate");
                    enode.put("iCalstate", write);
                    element.put(enode);
                }
            }
```

instead i am getting this it should only write at the first element, where the id is 0, but it's writing to each element:

```
{"scene": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "element": [
            {"iCalstate": "true"},
            {"iCalstate": "false"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "element": [
            {"iCalstate": "true"},
            {"iCalstate": "false"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "element": [
            {"iCalstate": "true"},
            {"iCalstate": "false"}
        ]
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a corresponding POJO for your JSON. And use `ObjectMapper` to map the JSON string and create an instance. You could then perform your desired operation on that instance.

Comment: Do you also know how i can do it with org.json ?